# Place iron-icon as prefix in paper-autocomplete

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

We can set `iron-icon` as prefix to `paper-input` like this

```
<paper-input label="username" id="inputWithButton">
  <iron-icon icon="mail" prefix></iron-icon>
  <div suffix>@email.com</div>
  <paper-icon-button suffix onclick="clearInput()" icon="clear" alt="clear" title="clear"></paper-icon-button>
</paper-input>
```

How to place this in `paper-automplete`?

I tried this but not working

```
<paper-autocomplete id="styled" min-length="1" source="{{data}}" placeholder="Search" disable-show-clear alwaysFloatLabel>
    <iron-icon icon="mail" prefix></iron-icon>
    <div suffix>@email.com</div>
    <paper-icon-button suffix onclick="clearInput()" icon="clear" alt="clear" title="clear"></paper-icon-button>
</paper-autocomplete>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

paper-autocomplete is not from Polymer developers. So it's not supporting prefix and postfix. As i am looking into source code, they don't really support it in any way. Also they already defined suffix as some kind of delete button.

https://github.com/ellipticaljs/paper-autocomplete/blob/master/paper-autocomplete.html

You have an option to edit their code ( i have no idea how about license ) or just make workaround with css positioning